# Pressure Sensor to Weight Sensor

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors, raspberry-pi2, raspberry-pi3

Is it possible to use the pressure sensor to act as a weight sensor?

In my understanding, the pressure sensor works on the amount of pressure put it to it, if the pressure is coming from the weight of an object, will it produce an output that is almost the same with the weighing scale?

I am working on a project right now and it involves sensor programming on Raspberry pi.

If this is possible can you help me on python coding of the pressure sensor?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You measure the force with your pressure sensor. Force is mass times acceleration. ([image: f = m \times a]). The gravitational acceleration on earth is ~ 9.80665 m/s². To get the mass of your object you need to calculate:

[image: m = \frac{f}{a}]

with a = 9.80665 m/s² and f is your sensor reading. Assuming that your sensor delivers values in Newtons (thanks Mark Perryman), then you have the mass in kg.

Comment: Note that this assumes that the pressure sensor returns a value for the Force in Newtons.

Comment: Also worth noting (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth) that the acceleration due to gravity varies between 9.77 to 9.83 depending on where you are in the world.

9.80665 is "Standard Gravity", but the implied extra precision might mislead.  (I would use 9.8 or 9.81 as the calculated mass will only be accurate to 2 or 3 significant figures anyway.)

Comment: Thanks for this very helpful information @Sender9. I am not yet acquainted with this formula. Is it safe to say that the pressure sensor measures the force with mass while the weight sensor is measuring the mass of an object without any force?

Comment: @Mark Perryman. I am not sure yet if the pressure sensor that Im looking for will return in Newtons. I haven't figure out yet which one to buy, Im still checking out Sparkfun for the best sensor that I need. Thanks for the link you have provided. This makes sense. So gravity is not constant anyway in all part of the world. Does this mean that, my weight may be different if I go to a place where gravity is 9.83 and 9.77?

Comment: @al123: Yes, the weight is different but the mass is the same. What you want is the mass (in kg). Weight (also called weight force) is measured in Newton.

Comment: Thanks @senden9. Yes I need the mass in lbs or kg. If I take the pressure sensor, I'll take the one with Newton output. Thanks you guys for the helpful information. Now I know what I need.

Comment: @al123: If the sensor return anything other that Newtons just a scaling factor should be needed. Assuming that the other scale is also linear.